# Manga about a girl helping souls in limbo

Tags: story-identification, manga

In the story a woman is in limbo as cake eating herself, a boy and girl go around redeeming lost souls turning them into angel, the boy dies and the girl tries healing him with a magic apple that a crow told her to use, crow lied and the boy dies.

Comment: You have to add at least a bit more detail. Where did you read this? Was it online or in print? When did you read this? Can you say anything about the artistic style, or even the book cover?

Comment: It was print, and on the cover it features a girl with a knife, wearing a dress made of cake with a slice missing, the slice is in her hand and she is eating it.

Comment: Bizenghast v.5? https://comicvine.gamespot.com/bizenghast-5-vol-5/4000-228178/

Comment: @Kreiri upon seeing the cover and reading the Wikipedia summary, I doubt that could be anything else. Please post that as an answer :)